# ngx-cookie - blank cookie object in server side rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, angular-universal

I have a angular application in which angular universal is enabled and i am rendering data from API but that includes the work of cookies. I make API call after checking a value in user browser cookies.

But for Angular SSR(server side rendering) there is no cookie and i am getting `{}` blank object when trying to use this `console.log(this.cookie.getAll());`.

I am using `ngx-cookie` package and my installation is this

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SlickCarouselModule } from 'ngx-slick-carousel';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TransferHttpCacheModule } from '@nguniversal/common';
import { NgtUniversalModule } from '@ng-toolkit/universal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    NgtUniversalModule,
    SlickCarouselModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { CookieService, CookieBackendService } from 'ngx-cookie';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: CookieService, useClass: CookieBackendService }]
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**server.ts**

I have applied this

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    req: req,
    res: res,
    providers: [
      {
        provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: (req)
      },
      {
        provide: 'RESPONSE', useValue: (res)
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Still i can only access cookies in browser but not server side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see the cookies in the `REQUEST` token?

Comment: @David no..cookies are blank on server side.

Comment: So that means that your cookies are either not set at all (check that they exist in y our browser) or that they not sent to the server (check the path and domain)

Comment: @David cookies do exist in browser and server side in server.ts file when i am logging `request.cookies` its also showing cookies but inside my service when i am using `this.cookie.getAll()` its showing me black object `{}` during server side rendering but returning cookie data when on browser

Comment: You can send cookies with every request to server using `Interceptor`

Comment: Did you find a solution to that issue? I am facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can send cookies with every request to server using `Interceptor`
Here is an example how to use it:

**intercreptor.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

@Injectable()

export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private cookies: CookieService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let token = this.cookies.get("my-access-token");

   if(token) req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
    });

    return next.handle(req)
  }

}
```

**intercreptor.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InterceptorService } from './interceptors/authorization';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorService,
      multi: true
   }]
})

export class InterceptorModule { }
```

and import `InterceptorModule` into your app.module.ts